# How to optimize Excel VBA coding for queryselector selecting modified URL in script

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, lowercase, queryselector

I tried the code below. Most of the execution time was stuck in `on error goto 0` and no success in further steps `.fireevent ("onchange")`. Is there some way I can optimize the process better?

```
Public Sub makeselections()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, var As String, ele As Object

var = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).value

With ie
.Visible = True
.Navigate2 "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/" & var & "/financials"

While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

With .document
  .querySelector("#autocomplete_input").value = var
  .querySelector("#investing_ac_button").Click
End With

While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

With .document
Do
 On Error Resume Next
   Set ele = .querySelector("[value^='/investing/stock/" & LCase(var) & "/financials/Income/quarter']")
 On Error GoTo 0

 Loop While ele Is Nothing
   .querySelector("[value^='/investing/stock/" & LCase(var) & "/financials/Income/quarter']").Selected = True
   .querySelector(".financials select").FireEvent "onchange"
 End With

 End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is presumably stuck as ele remains Nothing i.e. ticker is not found or at least that href value isn't found. Use a timed loop to allow for exit

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub MakeSelections()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, var As String, ele As Object, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10

    var = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Value

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/" & var & "/financials"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("#autocomplete_input").Value = var
            .querySelector("#investing_ac_button").Click
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            t = Timer
            Do
                On Error Resume Next
                Set ele = .querySelector("[value$='quarter']")
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While ele Is Nothing
            If ele Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            ele.Selected = True
            .querySelector(".financials select").FireEvent "onchange"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please also provide the value of _var_ as it aids in debugging.

Comment: Thanks HQarr's reply. I tried "ele" is always nothing and it doesn't work quarter financials. But stuck issue is fixed.

Comment: Cool. Please provide the value of _var_ when ele is nothing.

Comment: The value of var is always ticker in cells(1,1). ele is still nothing and then exit sub.

Comment: yes but I want a specific value to test with that occurs when ele is Nothing. For example, I tested with FB no problem. Which ticker are you having problems with?

Comment: With specific ticker like “MMM”, “AMZN” and “DE”, it works. But when var reads .cells(1,1) ele is always nothing. I’m wondering if url has some troubles with modification. How do you think of it, thanks?

Comment: I'm still confused. So, if you use "MMM" directly in the code it works but if you read it from cells(1,1) it fails?

Comment: Exactly! It stuck me.

Comment: Thanks QHarr. Now it's much stable. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I'd like to ask a new question for optimizing VBA .click in web script if you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure. Drop the link here when you have posted the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58445648/how-to-optimize-excel-vba-for-clicking-url