# How to optimize excel VBA for clicking url

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

Run time error "70" while VBA is running.

Sometime the code runs smooth but sometime does not. Wondering if there is more reliable code for proceeding. It always stop in `If link.innerHTML = "Balance Sheet" Then end if`

```
Public Sub Get()

Dim ie As Object
Dim URL As String, link As Object, alllinks As Object
Dim eRowa As Long, eRowb As Long, eRowc As Long
Dim var As Object

Set var = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1)
URL = "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/" & var & "/financials"

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With ie

    .Visible = True
    .navigate URL

    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

    Set alllinks = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

    For Each link In alllinks

         If link.innerHTML = "Balance Sheet" Then

             link.Click

         End If

    Next link

    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

End With

Set ie = Nothing


End Sub
```

Expect smooth running without error 70

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a timed loop to wait for presence of `a` tag. Use an [attribute = value css selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) with $ ends with operator for faster targeting of the appropriate element

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ie As Object, url As String, link As Object
    Dim var As Range, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10

    Set var = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1)

    url = "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/" & var.value & "/financials"

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate2 url

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        t = Timer
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set link = .document.querySelector("[href$='/balance-sheet']")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While link Is Nothing

        If link Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        link.Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Stop '<== Delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you still get an error 70 please provide the appropriate ticker.

Comment: Thanks QHarr. It worked better when I tried it in serval days. Appreciate!

Comment: "onchange" function I still doesn't understand. Can you give me for tips or understanding, thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58515101/how-vba-to-code-fireevent-on-change-in-selected-terms-in-javascript