# VBA + IE Automation - can't get Element ID

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, getelementbyid

I am trying to scrape some information from an internal company website. My code is able to launch a new IE window and navigate successfully to the page but when I try and input data into a box I keep getting errors.

I've switched various things around based off the posts i've read but always get some sort of error.

For the code posted below it's this error on the last line:

[Object Variable or With Block Not Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ITMH.png)

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Sub PerformancePull()

    Dim appIE As Object
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim StartDate As Variant
    Dim MyDoc As HTMLDocument

    Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium


    sURL = "website"

    With appIE
        .navigate sURL
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Do While appIE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set MyDoc = appIE.document

    Set StartDate = MyDoc.getElementById("ct100_assoc_tbEndDate")
    StartDate.Value = "3/25/2020"

End Sub
```

Edit:

Here's a piece of the HTML code that identifies the ID I'm trying to capture:
[image: HTML SnipIt]

Comment: Maybe include the part of the source of the page in question that has the relevant HTML in your question, or at least a link to the page... without either of those things it's impossible for anyone to help you.

Comment: Use a proper page load wait and potentially a timed loop for presence of item located by id (assuming you can access direct with id) e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58445978/6241235

Comment: Thank you - I tried the wait methods in earlier iterations of my own trouble shooting and still didn't make a difference. It must be something with the website i'm trying to access. it's an internal company website. I've posted a snipit of the HTML that identifies the Element i'm trying interact with. Please let me know if it'd be helpful to see any other pieces of the HTML. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

*Try the following*

*Remove this*

```
Set StartDate = MyDoc.getElementById("ct100_assoc_tbEndDate")
StartDate.Value = "3/25/2020"
```

*And replace it with this*

```
With MyDoc
    .getElementById("ct100_assoc_tbEndDate").Value = "3/25/2020"
End With
```

Comment: Hi - thank you for the suggestion. I tried that but it did not work. It must be something with the website i'm trying to access. it's an internal company website. I've posted a snipit of the HTML that identifies the Element i'm trying interact with. Please let me know if it'd be helpful to see any other pieces of the HTML. thanks again.

Comment: I'm running it out of a module.

Comment: I mean Excel, Outlook? 2010 or ... @Matt

Comment: So sorry. Excel 2016. Thank you

Comment: @Matt thats okay, one more thing- can you post the `html` as text not image, also post the complete html exampe.  `<td style="test-align: center;"` TO `</td>`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to test your code on my side and it worked fine without any error. Below is the testing result.

[image]

I suggest you try to access the element and assign the value like below to check whether it works or not.

```
appIE.document.getElementById("ct100_assoc_tbEndDate").Value = "3/25/2020"
```

Let us know about your testing results if the issue persists then we will try to provide further suggestions.

Comment: Thank you - The code still isn't working on my end. It must be something with the website i'm trying to access. it's an internal company website. I've posted a snipit of the HTML that identifies the Element i'm trying interact with. Please let me know if it'd be helpful to see any other pieces of the HTML. thanks again.

Comment: You had declared the StartDate As Variant. It is possible that it is not assigning that object properly. Try to declare StartDate As HTMLInputElement and then again try to run your code to see whether it works or not.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It did as you suggested and am still getting the same error on the last line (StartDate.Value = "3/25/20"). I believe you are right in your suggestion however. The line directly above seems to not be setting that variable correctly. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is it possible for you to test this code on any other machine? I think code is correct because I also tested it with Excel 2016 on Win 10 OS and you can see that it is working fine. It can possible that some issues caused by the VBA editor.